# Get customize Path of File found with os.walk

Tags: python, path, operating-system, os.walk

**I am trying to expose the selective path of a file, found using os.walk. The walk function is working correctly and is exposing all the files I want however right now I am able to expose either only the file name or full path of the file.**

`path = 'C:/Users/testing_recurssion'
for root, d_names, f_names in os.walk(path):
    for name in f_names:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))`

**This returns**
`C:/Users/testing_recurssion\folder1\file3.txt`
`C:/Users/testing_recurssion\folder1\folder3\file4.txt`

**However, I want it to return**
`folder1\file3.txt`
`folder1\folder3\file4.txt`**

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.relpath`

```
directory = "C:/Users/testing_recurssion"
for root, d_names, f_names in os.walk(directory):
    for name in f_names:
        path = os.path.join(root, name)
        print(os.path.relpath(path, directory))
```

Also - consider using `pathlib.Path` which is more recent and object oriented:

```
from pathlib import Path

directory = Path("C:/Users/testing_recurssion")
for path in directory.rglob("*"):
    print(path.relative_to(directory))
```